# Rails 4. Activerecord validation rules and callbacks are being disabled after unicorn restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, unicorn

I use Ruby v2.2.3, Rails v4.2.4, Unicorn v5.1.0 in production.

Activerecord validation rules and callbacks for all models of app has been disabled after unicorn restart (from log rotation script). Here it is

```
    /var/www/fitness_crm/shared/log/production.log
/var/www/fitness_crm/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log
/var/www/fitness_crm/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log {
        daily
        missingok
        rotate 30
        compress
        notifempty
        create 640 deploy deploy
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                kill -s USR2 `cat /var/www/fitness_crm/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
        endscript
}
```

We've changed the script to send USR1 instead USR2, but nothing has changed. When USR1 is sent validations/callbacks simply keep being disabled. Here is our unicorn configuration file

```
working_directory "/var/www/fitness_crm/current"
pid "/var/www/fitness_crm/shared/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stdout_path "/var/www/fitness_crm/shared/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
stderr_path "/var/www/fitness_crm/shared/log/unicorn.stderr.log"

listen "/tmp/unicorn.fitness_crm_production.sock"

worker_processes 8
timeout 30

preload_app true

before_exec do |server|
  ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] = "/var/www/fitness_crm/current/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # Disconnect since the database connection will not carry over
  if defined? ActiveRecord::Base
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  # Quit the old unicorn process
  old_pid = "#{server.config[:pid]}.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end

  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis.quit
  end

  sleep 1
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # Start up the database connection again in the worker
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

  if defined?(Resque)
    Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'
  end
end
```

After this we kill unicorn and start it manually with command:

```
bundle exec unicorn -D -c /var/www/fitness_crm/shared/config/unicorn.rb -E production
```

After this everything is good and validations and callbacks are enabled again.
Please, help to find out what is the reason of such a behavior and how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see why anything above would affect callbacks or validations being run, at all. Do you have any special behaviour in the app, e.g. a `skip_callbacks` method? Or is all access to the database lost (so it's not simply the callbacks that are failing, but rather *nothing* is running)? Or maybe when you say "callbacks", you're actually talking about background jobs, which aren't reconnecting to Redis??

Comment: Tom, DB is running. Records are being saved, but with skipped validations and callbacks. I mean exactly activerecord validations and callbacks. I googled for this and hadn't found anything. After manual unicorn kill and start everything works fine again. I've reported to unicorn and rails community too. Waiting for answer everywhere

Comment: And we don't use skip_callbacks anywhere

Comment: A possible cause could be (in rails 4): If `false` is returned somewhere in the callbacks, then the rest of the callback chain is halted. Could it be the since something is not properly reconnecting, you are returning `false` before all (or some?) callbacks?

Comment: ...But it still shouldn't *save* the record!! An exception (`ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved`) would be thrown instead! (Again, unless you are doing something funny with rescuing this exception.)

Comment: No one rescue of RecordNotSaved exception (if not somewhere in gems).I'll double check for returning false in callbacks and validation rules

Comment: By the way, in my scenario validations and callback are being disabled for whole project but not only for one record.

Comment: In 5 years of working on the framework, I've never heard of this. If this really is happening, you must have some obscure, bespoke "skip all callbacks if..." going on.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest without diving into the full code base... Check the full stack trace of a `save` action, to see if anything bizarre pops up? Maybe someone has overloaded that method, with special behaviour, e.g. executing raw SQL or a stored procedure?!